# Doing a case sensitive vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Does anyone know how to do a case sensitive vlookup with excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can pick up the first, second, third, etc. matches by forcing the non-matches into an error state and ignoring the errors. Modify this method using the [EXACT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EXACT-function-243E2BC1-93D6-4FD5-9608-DC3C5B8C046B) to choose a case-sensitive lookup.

```
nam     date            code
bob     19-Oct-2015     001
BOB     02-Nov-2015     002
boB     28-Oct-2015     002
Bob     24-Oct-2015     004
bOB     27-Oct-2015     005
bOb     21-Oct-2015     006
```

Pick **Bob** and **BOB** from the mix with,

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$7, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$6)/EXACT($A$2:$A$7, $E2), 1))
```

Fill down and right as necessary.

[image: Case sensitive VLOOKUP]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The key issue to a complete solution here is as Dick Kusleika observes: avoiding stopping the search when a case-insensitive match is found before the case sensitive one.

The Blog entry [Case Sensitive Lookup in Excel](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2009/10/16/case-sensitive-lookup-in-excel/) claims to have a solution to this problem using the INDEX and MATCH functions (original info courtesy a post by Peo Sjoblom).  There are some alternatives in the comments too.

Comment: FWIW, that works, but only if you can do array formulas (hitting ctrl-shift-enter to enter the formula). The problem I had was that the POI library I use to create excel files does not support those types of formulas. I found no other solution which used non-array formulas, so I was forced to do a solution which I dislike, but which is the only option that I had. I pre-process all values and add unicode characters \u0096\u0097 in front of each lowercase character (for each field that needs to be case sensitive). Those characters are invisible, but they are compared by MATCH in excel.

Comment: This formula suggested in the comments appears to be the simplest solution: `=LOOKUP(1,1/EXACT(A1:A6,D1),B1:B6)`

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be a feature of vlookup that case does not matter - so Bob is the same as bob.  You could use code() to convert to ASCII and lookup on code.  This would make your lookup more complicated, and code() only returns the code for the first item in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If the value you are returning is a number and not text, and if the first column of your lookup_table is unique ('bob' doesn't appear more than once), then you can use an array formula like this

```
=SUM(EXACT(A3:A6,"bob")*(B3:B6))
```

Enter with Control+Shift+Enter, not just enter.  It sums everything in B3:B6 where A3:A6 is exactly "bob".  Since there's only one "bob", it's only summing one cell.  Because it uses SUM, returning strings won't work.

If 'bob' appears more than once, it will sum all the values, which you probably don't want.

**Update**

If the value you are looking up is not a number, you could use an array formula to find the row, then wrap an INDEX function around it.  Assume your data is A3:B6 and you want to pull data out of column B based on an exact match in column A.

```
=INDEX(A3:B6,SUM(EXACT(A3:A6,"bob")*(ROW(B3:B6)))-2,2)
```

Enter with CSE.  The SUM portion returns the row where "bob" is found.  You have to subtract 2 from it because the data starts in A3 (subtract one less than the row where the data starts).  The INDEX function uses that row and pulls from column B.

Comment: @dick thank you. i have one column on one worksheet, but the other column (the column that i am matching on in another worksheet, so ur formula does not work in my case)

Comment: Nor would VLOOKUP, case-sensitive or not.  You might consider editing your question with more info about how the data is laid out.  I'm sure there's a solution.

Comment: It does?  That's a new one on me.  Can you give me an example of that?

Comment: @dick try it. what example do u need

Comment: Any working example will be fine.  This formula =VLOOKUP(1,Sheet1:Sheet3!A3:B7,3,FALSE) returns a #VALUE error.  Since the second argument has to be a contiguous range, I'm not sure how to references ranges on multiple sheets.

Answer (score -1):

My first thought is to use the EXACT() function to test the result of the vlookup:

```
=IF(EXACT(VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$C$4,1,FALSE),A2),VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$C$4,1,FALSE),0)
```

Where A2 = the value you wish to look up and C2:C4 is the range containing the values to look up.

This would return the result of the vlookup and confirm that it matched the case of the value you wish to look up. It would return the vlookup result if they match case, or 0 otherwise.

**EDITED**

Actually this answer wouldn't work. If your list contained "Bob" and "bob" it would find the first one and only test that. Sorry, I didn't think of that.

Comment: I tried that yesterday, and Jenny said it didn't work, but maybe you'll have better luck than I did.